# Getting issue in get id from youtube API

Tags: android, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am trying to get Id from Youtube API in android app but unable to find

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=id&forUsername={username}&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

But getting this response:

```
    {
 "kind": "youtube#channelListResponse",
 "etag": "\"sNu6csVZt536JdlmpOxN9WQSd8U/ewwRz0VbTYpp2EGbOkvZ5M_1mbo\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 0,
  "resultsPerPage": 5
 },
 "items": []
}
```

I have also tried with this

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=id%2CcontentDetails&mine=true&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

But a response is below:

```
    {
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "youtube.parameter",
    "reason": "authorizationRequired",
    "message": "The request uses the \u003ccode\u003emine\u003c/code\u003e parameter but is not properly authorized.",
    "locationType": "parameter",
    "location": "mine"
   }
  ],
  "code": 401,
  "message": "The request uses the \u003ccode\u003emine\u003c/code\u003e parameter but is not properly authorized."
 }
}
```

Comment: Did you manage to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

make sure you are logged-in with OAuth when performing these calls and if you're going to parse the JSON response to look for the id, it's found in `items.id`

Tried this with [Channels.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) Try-it and I got correct response:

```
/**
 * API response
 */
{
  "kind": "youtube#channelListResponse",
  "etag": "\"VPWTmrH7dFmi4s1RqrK4tLejnRI/X6OHzHqUUEu1okILXdfdfBbUxU\"",
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 1,
    "resultsPerPage": 1
  },
  "items": [
    {
      "kind": "youtube#channel",
      "etag": "\"VPWTmrH7dFmi4s1RqrK4tLejfdf/Qw3dXynuD_IdfB1LMKjSeiDI\"",
      "id": "UCTjdfopNLdfd5yXVv93Ww"
    }
  ]
}
```